# Something went wrong in the port forwarding

Tags: apache, networking, webserver, portforwarding

I tried to run a vertrigo server(HTTP web server) on my pc on port 8888 but I keep fail.
I used the TCPView program in order to see if I have an activity on this port and the result was negative. this port is free to use.
But somehow the vertrigo is saying the opposite.
In the picture the message is about port 80 but I changed it correctly for sure(I've done it many times in other pc's) to 8888.

[image]

I also tried to disable the firewall and the result was the same.

Answer (score 0):

What version of VertrigoServ are you using? I hade the very same problem with version 2.29, but rolling back to [version 2.28](http://sourceforge.net/projects/vertrigo/files/VertrigoServ/2.28/Vertrigo_228.exe/download) solved the problem for me.

Comment: 2.29, do you have a link to 2.28?